# Prevent .Net Framework from Loading Assemblies from Current Working Directory

Tags: c#, .net, security

I've got a customer complaining to me that our software violates MITRE's [CWE-427: Uncontrolled Search Path Element](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/427.html).

Which basically says: It's bad to load assemblies from directories that an attacker can access. It specifically calls out: "such as '/tmp' or the current working directory"

Our app is meant to be portable and has no external dependencies that need to be included in the current working directory. We are not making any Assembly.Load calls or P/Invokes.
However, we do rely on the .Net Framework assemblies and apparently you can hijack its assembly loading.

Here's a simple C++ DLL:

```
#include <windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HANDLE hDll, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        system("whoami > %temp%\\whoami.txt");
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

If you name the resulting assembly propsys.dll and put it beside the EXE of the following .NET Framework project:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestConsoleApp_NetFramework
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process.Start("Cmd.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

When ran this you will load our fake propsys.dll and write a whoami.txt file to the user's temp folder.

Is there any way to tell it to *only* load assemblies from the Windows or System32 directory? Or maybe ensure that the .Net Framework only loads official binaries? Or at least only signed ones?

I've read plenty of threads on this but they all seem to address dynamically loading via Assembly.Load or P/Invokes. Nothing I've tried has prevented the hijack above.

Now, I know someone's going to call out the obvious: if they have access to the working directory then it's game over already, they can just overwrite your EXE. While that's true, we can (and our customers absolutely do) use code signing to ensure that our own EXE is permitted to be ran. So it becomes a problem of sorts if our signed and trusted EXE can be hijacked by a rogue assembly file that we ourselves don't even directly load. I still feel this whole thing is sort of stupid, but ok, an effort will be made.

Note: This doesn't seem to be a problem in .Net 8 and I'm presuming it's non-Framework predecessors. However, because we're trying to make a portal EXE for Windows we target the lowest supported .Net Framework to ensure that it's there on the box.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from shipping a .NET Framework executable that does nothing more than download the .NET 8 runtime and use it to execute a .NET 8 application that contains your actual program logic. If you feel like that's a worthwhile investment of resources to fix a "vulnerability" that is moot if the attacker has write access to that directory, go ahead. Or you could just tell that customer to stop wasting your time with stupidity.

Comment: You could add NuGet package `Costura.Fody`, which is an assembly weaver.  It merges all the assemblies into your final EXE.  Now in your Bin folder, those DLL's may appear, but you can delete them and only use the EXE and App.Config.

Comment: @IanKemp: Yea, I feel you. In digging into it today though I found a couple references from MS that basically say the same thing*.  ex: MS's C++ compiler has DEPENDENTLOADFLAG; was wonder if .Net had something similar.


*[Secure loading of libraries to prevent DLL preloading attacks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/secure-loading-of-libraries-to-prevent-dll-preloading-attacks-d41303ec-0748-9211-f317-2edc819682e1)
[How can I try to escape the disease-ridden hot-tubs known as the TEMP and Downloads directories?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230328-00/?p=107978)